# Promise changes response while returning it to Redux Saga

Tags: fetch, redux-saga

i'm facing a problem, i have fetch function fired in saga

```
const fetchComments = () =>
  fetch(url, {
    method: 'POST',
  })
    .then((r) => r.json())
    .then((r) => {
      console.log('FETCH', r);
      //return r;
    });
```

And when i console.log response without returning it, it works fine and i get an object that has a propperty **data**, propperty **items** inside data which is an array of objects **item** f.e., and every item has propperty **text** which is a string, *"10 -*/)(:$#@2! 20"* in my specific case. Uncommenting return r affects order in **items** arrays, specifically reverses it, and string in **text** propperty is being sliced, leaving me with *"@2! 20"*.

I've tried console.trace() in saga, but this did not lead to anything, all executed functions and methods in both cases are the same.

Comment: How can it "work fine" if your function doesn't return anything? That "reorganization" of the object happens in some other location you are not showing us ... Please provide a minimial reproducible example ...

Comment: @derpirscher i mean it console logged propper data in console.log('FETCH', r);

Comment: And you mean that `console.log` gets scrambled if you uncomment the `return r` statement? I doubt that